# Understanding when to use plain HTML CSS JS vs Frameworks

Tags: web-development, web

Looking at the web development landscape I see that there is two approach to making websites.

- If the site is simple you're better of using HTML, CSS and JS.
- If the site is complexe it's worth it to use a frontend framework.

I have trouble understanding what a simple website means in this context. Is an e-commerce website a simple site? It does not have many interactions from users (selecting items, checking out,etc...).
Do we refer to only static websites(ex: blogs but even blogs have interactivity with user comments)?
Is YouTube a simple site?

So what is the extent of the "simple website" category that you're better of using plain HTML CSS and JS?

Comment: Instead of "simple/complex"  i would prefer **static content** (something you can write in a html-editor, that never changes) and **dynamic content** (something that changes, i.e. when you display the curent time on the webpage, or stock contentent of a certain article in a shop)

Comment: @k3b During my years doing this, I've created both complex static sites and simple dynamic sites.

Answer (score 4):

Until you’ve done both you won’t know the limitations.

Frameworks come in many different flavors. Most, effectively give you a different, domain specific, language to work in. If you happen to have the problems they solve they can speed things along. If you have different problems they can paint you into a corner.

It’s easier to tell which is happening when you’ve got experience working without them under you belt. Gives you a baseline perspective on what’s possible with how much work.

Do the work it takes to know more then one way to solve these problems. Only then will you know the difference between help and hype.